# (MFC) Always display the same sized UI indefendent of Per Monitor HiDPI

Tags: mfc, dpi

I want to always display UI in 96 dpi size without being affected by DPI per monitor.

When the window moves or resizes, the coordinates come in differently depending on the DPI, destroying the UI.

When I receive the `WM_DPICHANGE` message and `OnSize`, should I recalculate according to the current DPI value?

There are so many dialogs and controls, and the code is vast, which is frustrating.
Is there a simple way to do it?

++
Is there a way to specify the DPI scale process independent of Windows DPI?

Comment: Can you just turn off DPI-awareness for the whole project?

Comment: What does *"the same size"* mean to you? The same number of pixels in device units, or the same number of pixels in logical units?

Comment: @Adrian Mole I can turn off DPI awareness. However, it stretches the bitmap on Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable//First of all, I apologize for my stupid English skills.
The same size means that when the control size is changed, the x,y values passed to OnSize will be received as 96dpi at any dpi scale!.

My project has a lot of Control UI and I need to put everything on one screen. It should always be displayed in the size you see at 96dpi.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your use-case?

Comment: @CodyGray//The end user wants it.
There are several buttons and list controls on one screen, all displayed on one screen at 96dpi. However, it is said to be inconvenient because it cannot be displayed on one screen at high dpi.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that when the controls are scaled up at high DPIs, they get too large to fit on one screen? The solution to that isn't fixing the DPI level. It's detecting the DPI change and reducing the size of the controls.